# REST API Security JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: rest

I am coding a webapp (E-commerce) for learning purpose using AngularJS + BootStrap and REST.
I have used Apache Wink for REST WS and and application is deployed on JBoss EAP 6.4.  My application is working fine.

I can access the back end data using AJAX and webpages are getting populated properly. The issue is security of REST WAS. If I use REST URL directly on browser, without going through front end, JSON data gets populated and my data is exposed. What design changes should i do ?

Please note that initial operation on the website for e.g. browsing the products, adding them to cart etc are stateless. No user's identity is needed for these operations. I still need to secure my data for these interactions. Please suggest, how can I do it.

Sunil

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock down the services, you may require some type of authentication (for example user/pass) that returns a security token (over https).  Then all subsequent function calls may require the security token to be passed in as a parameter (if the operation is sensitive).  The token will require a session timeout.

However, if the data is also publically shown on the site, then there's not really a security risk in itself.  IOW, how is this any different than them using the public website to get/update data?  The rest services usually shouldn't require any additional level of security beyond what is already used on the website to protect the data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was going though the Spring Security tutorial where it does secure a resource even if there is no user's identity required.  https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#add-a-home-page ..... Can we do something like this ? I can certainly secure other resoiurces which are user specific using the security token etc. but could not find a way for securing other WS calls.

Comment: If you don't want to require a user supplied identity, you can use a similar same concept but supply the credential from the server side.  For example: a server side function calls getRandomToken() and sets it in the authenticated session.  Then drop this token in the web page as a javascript variable (server side).  Then this token may be passed back for all the subsequent calls and compared to the session token.   I think all the methods are going to revolve around using some shared secret.